# YouTube url is incomplete

Tags: android, url, video, webview, youtube-iframe-api

I'm working on an android app which has a `webview` and it is used to play *YouTube videos*. I also have a `Textview` which shows the **url** of the currently playing video.But sometimes when a video is playing, it does not show the video id of the playing video in the url. It only shows https://m.youtube.com/
But when I refresh the same video, then the complete **url** is shown as https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Wm9qCz63dQE
I'm setting values to the `Textview` using `webview.getOriginalUrl()` method and I use iframe *API* to play the YouTube video in webview.
Am i doing anything wrong while getting the url or is there any other way of getting the complete url of a youtube video?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `webchromeclient()` of the **WebView** to get progress , you will  get the original **url** once you complete the 100% of loading then it shows you original **url**

```
webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) 
               if(progress == 100) {
               Log.d("original url",""+webview.getOriginalUrl();
               }
            }
        });
```